# $|x - a_1||x - a_2|...|x - a_{2n}| = (n!)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial, absolute-value

Let $a_i \in \mathbb N$ ; $a_i \neq a_j$ and $i , j = 1 , 2 ,... , 2n$

If $|x - a_1||x - a_2|...|x - a_{2n}| = (n!)^2$. Find $x$ in terms of $a$.

I’ve remove 2n absolute to 1 absolute value of 2n deg polynomial with all as its root.

Comment: What is  $a$, a number, a sequence  ?

Comment: Sorry , I’ve add wrong tag.

Comment: @EDX 2n distinct positive integers

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: Remove 2n absolute value to 1 absolute value of polynomial with all a as a root.

Comment: Could detail it in your post, in order for all contributors to properly help you ?